# Why doesn't this SED command work?

Tags: linux, unix, sed, gnu

I am trying to replace all strings in a line which match the pattern `.*q=` or `HTTP` with empty string.

I am using the below command for the same.

```
sed s/.\*q=\|HTTP.*//
```

But this doesn't work. It doesn't replace the string with the empty string. Can you please let me know if there is anything wrong with the above command.

Comment: Can you give us string examples? Problem may come from shell expansion.

Answer (score 3):

this line should work for your requirement:

```
sed s'/\.\*q=\|HTTP//g'
```

for example:

```
kent$  echo "leave.*q=justHTTP foo"|sed s'/\.\*q=\|HTTP//g'        
leavejust foo
```

your command:

- better quote expressions in sed command
- if you want to replace  all occurrences of pattern, in your case is .*q or HTTP, you need a `g` flag in your `s/../../`
- if you just want to replace `HTTP` you should not add `.*` at the end of it, otherwise it will remove all string after HTTP inclusively.
- if you want to match literature string `.*`, you need escape `.` **and** `*`

Comment: How can I change this to match only lines more than 3 characters after applying the above filter?

Comment: @bourne you want to 1step apply the replace on all lines, 2step, output the line with `length>=3`? if you want this, you could pipe the sed output to `sed ...|awk 'length>=3'` well, two steps could be done by awk alone by awk's `gsub`. but it is not for you original question.

Comment: Yeah I want the 2nd step output length>=3. Thanks

Comment: Yeah thanks it worked. I have a query. Why do you have to escape '|' but not '*' or '.' in the sed regex?

Comment: @bourne `. * and |` were all escaped. have you read the codes in my answer?